# Why does my google chrome search engine box always appear empty?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-search

Why does my google chrome search engine box always appear empty? First thought I was entering search sites like amazon incorrectly. Then realized that I could not see the site I had just entered, no matter how carefully I input them.

Comment: Which box? There's more than 1 place where search engines show up.